# arithmetic comparisons on numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.eye(3)
>>> x[1, 2] = .5
>>> x
array([[ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  1. ,  0.5],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  1. ]])
>>> 0 < x.any() < 1
False
>>>
```

I would like to check if numpy array contains any value between 0 and 1.
I read `0 < x.any() < 1` as 'if there is any element with size greater then 0 and less then 1, return true', but that's obviously not the case.

How can I do arithmetic comparison on numpy array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> np.any((0 < x) & (x < 1))
True
```

What `x.any()` actually does: it's the same as `np.any(x)`, meaning it returns `True` if any elements in `x` are nonzero. So your comparison is `0 < True < 1`, which is false because in python 2 `0 < True` is true, but `True < 1` is not, since `True == 1`.

In this approach, by contrast, we make boolean arrays of whether the comparison is true for each element, and then check if any element of that array is true:

```
>>> 0 < x
array([[ True, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> x < 1
array([[False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> (0 < x) & (x < 1)
array([[False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

You have to do the explicit `&`, because unfortunately numpy doesn't (and I think can't) work with python's built-in chaining of comparison operators.

Comment: I get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` using your code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was faking it initially (always forget that operator chaining doesn't work in numpy). Updated, with explanations.

Comment: The reason comparison chaining doesn't (and can't) work with numpy arrays is that python interprets `a<b<c` as `a<b and b<c`, while with numpy arrays, we need it to be interpreted as `a<b & b<c`

Comment: @shx2 It would technically be possible (I think) if numpy chose to interpret `a and b` like `a & b`. It doesn't, though, and that's probably a good choice overall – just one I often forget about. :)

Comment: You can't overload the boolean `and` and `or` operators in python. It's not numpy's choice.

Comment: You're right, of course. I thought you could get around it with some trickery involving `__bool__`/`__nonzero__`, but it seems like not.

Answer (score 1):

Your code first tests `x.any()`, which evaluates to `True`, as `x` includes a nonzero value. It then tests `0 < True (=1) < 1`, which is `False`. Do:

```
((0 < x) & (x < 1)).any()
```