# numpy.where() function for exact matches only?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, match

Just a curiosity i can't seem to figure out, it must be something simple! Any thoughts would be very helpful!

Two arrays, only one value in y matches any value in x. My code will iterate over each value in x and find the matching values in y and calculate the distance to each one. The minimum distance it has to go to find a matching value is entered in z[i,j]

It works until I change the 1 to 1.1 and I try allow for some variation in the value Its looking for. If the "1" in y can vary between 0.9 -1.0 how can i account for it?

```
x = [[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1]]
y = [[2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,1,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2]]

xx = numpy.array(x)
yy = numpy.array(y)

zz = numpy.ones((5,5))

for i in range(0,5):
    for j in range(0,5):
        match = numpy.where((xx[i,j] == yy))

        distance = sqrt((i-(np.array(match[0])))**2 + (j -(np.array(match[1])))**2)
        zz[i,j] = min(distance)
```

I have tried variations of:

```
match = numpy.where((yy-0.1 <= xx[i,j] <= yy+0.1))
```

"Error:ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Comment: by the way ... there is a missing `)` in front of the second `**2`

Comment: I think it is in front of `**2` ... not behind ... unless you want square roots of negative numbers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it is just about avoiding the error, try

```
numpy.where((yy-0.1 <= xx[i,j]) & (xx[i,j] <= yy+0.1))
```

Comment: perfect! Thanks for that. 

As "and" is just a logical comparison function, why would it not work in this case?

Comment: I think `and` works only for lists with a single element whereas `&` is applied element-wise on two arrays

Comment: `and` is a Python operator that works with 2 boolean scalars.  It 'knows' nothing about `numpy` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

About the error, it is explained in more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15395127/2096752) (among other places).

Alternatively, you could simply use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html). Like:

```
numpy.where(numpy.isclose(xx[i,j],yy, atol=0.1))
```